# Celery/Redis some (many) messages getting dropped

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

I'm using Celery (2.2.4) with Redis (v.2.2.2) as my message broker.

Any idea what would cause SOME (most) messages to randomly and inconsistently get lost?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that seems logical is that you exceed the memory that your redis-instance uses. So some messages are discarded ( with LRU policy (?) ).